# Web browser control's URL shows javascript:false;

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am using a web browser control in a window form. Whenever I open a web site in my web browser control it sometimes shows an absolute URL ( e.g. `https://employer.dice.com/daf/servlet/DAFctrl`) and then suddenly it changes to  `javascript:false;`.

When I use a regular web browser to open the same link then it does not change the URL to `javascript:false;`.

```
private void webBrowser_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        tbUrl.Text = e.Url.ToString();

    }
```

Any idea how to resolve this kind of issue?

Comment: Can you post the code where you affect the Url in the WebControl and the url you use to test it?

Comment: @Askolein i posted in Question Body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is up to you how to handle navigation events. Browsers probably supress navigation events that doesn't change the current resource. You could do the same:

```
private void webBrowser_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser browser = sender as WebBrowser;
    // only change the url if the Scheme is not javascript
    if (!e.Url.Scheme.StartsWith(
                       "javascript",  
                       StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
        && ( browser !=null && (e.Url.AbsolutePath == browser.Url.AbsolutePath)) )
    {
        tbUrl.Text = e.Url.ToString();
    }   

}
```

Comment: i used this  ` if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != webBrowser.Url.AbsolutePath)
                    return;`  and it handled

Comment: I can see why that works. If however the webBrowser.Url ever gets set to an url that you need to be supressed your code will let it true. Glad it worked out well for you.

Comment: rene i used this inside the document complete event. Because your code helped to suppressed "javascript" but on document complete event i  watch whenever i-frame loads it fires and different different url were generating.

Comment: OK, that scenario didn't spring to mind, I added your option... tnx for the feedback.